# lighttpd redirect http://www to https://www

Tags: redirect, https, lighttpd

I'm trying to redirect domain.com to https://www.domain.com.

I have the following rule:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^domain\.com$" {
url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://www.domain.com/$1" )
}
```

It works for http://domain.com -> https://www.domain.com but it doesn't work for http://www.domain.com.

Any thoughts?

PS: I have other domains on the conf file so I need a rule just for domain.com.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should work:

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":80" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "^domain\.com$" {
        url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://www.domain.com/$1" )
    }
}
$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "^domain\.com$" {
        url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://www.domain.com/$1" )
    }
}
```

Or you could use something like this... whichever suits your particular set up better:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^domain\.com$" {
    url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://www.domain.com/$1" )
}

$HTTP["scheme"] == "http" {
    $HTTP["host"] =~ "^www\.domain\.com$" {
        url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://www.domain.com/$1" )
    }
}
```